# Multiple p value calculation function (Chi2 test)

Tags: python

I am struggling here. Just finding my way through Python, so excuse my question.
I have data composed of more than 30 categorical variables. I want to test p value of all these columns against other columns: gender, occupation, education and residence.
Is there any function to automate this process, because they are more than 100 entries.
Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

Comment: Thanks. Though I could not find related info there

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.